# Triple DES C# Error: Specified initialization vector(IV) does not match the block size for this algorithm

Tags: c#, encryption, tripledes

I am running the following code in C# to decrypt a ciphertext (A19E14B80C19B70925A93DBC9250EB2EC1B6365DCDE42B9F1E44CD4D9AA246BA) that was generated with a Triple-DES-CBC with PKCS5Padding under IV (D160A98F71D5251A) with a given Triple DES key (43451943D61940EE3DF251C34B649EAB602DF3BAE61). All of those are in hex format. However, when I run the code, I keep getting the error: Specified initialization vector(IV) does not match the block size for this algorithm. Can anyone help me figure out why my code isn't working?

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public class MyClass
{
    public static void RunDecrypt()
    {
        string result = TripleDesDecrypt("A19E14B80C19B70925A93DBC9250EB2EC1B6365DCDE42B9F1E44CD4D9AA246BA");
        WL(result);

        // PAUSE
        RL();
    }

    static string TripleDesDecrypt(string Data)
    {
        byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("43451943D61940EE3DF251C34B649EAB602DF3BAE61");
        byte[] iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("D160A98F71D5251A");
        byte[] data = StringToByteArray(Data);
        byte[] enc = new byte[0];
        TripleDES tdes = TripleDES.Create();
        tdes.IV = iv;
        tdes.Key = key;
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
        ICryptoTransform ict = tdes.CreateDecryptor();
        enc = ict.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(enc);
    }

    public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
    {
        int NumberChars = hex.Length;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
            bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        return bytes;
    }

    #region Helper methods

    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            RunDecrypt();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string error = string.Format("---\nThe following error occurred while executing the snippet:\n{0}\n---", e.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(error);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.Write("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    private static void WL(object text, params object[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(text.ToString(), args);
    }

    private static void RL()
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Break()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: If everything (especially key and IV) are hex encoded, you would also have to hex decode everything (analog to the ciphertext), which would result in an 8 bytes IV as required. However your key is only 43 chars long, so it is probably incomplete (hex encoding has an even number of chars). Btw, [TripleDES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Keying_options) keys have a length of 16 bytes (32 chars) for 2TDEA or 24 bytes (48 chars) for 3TDEA.

Comment: My apologies, but what do you mean by "analog to the ciphertext"?

Comment: The ciphertext is hex decoded with `StringToByteArray()`, this must also be done with the key and the IV if they are hex encoded as you write (however as already mentioned the key seems to be incomplete).

Comment: Normally, the entire key should be known. If the encrypting side has given you this key, you should contact them and point out that a TripleDES key is 16 or 24 bytes long. You can of course try to guess/complete the key, but depending on how corrupted it is, this may not be successful.

Comment: I found out the problem, there were a couple characters missing from the key, the actual length was 48. I implemented your solution and it worked, thanks!